# Why child elements of body element don't inherit/reference to, the height property of parent element?

Tags: html, css

```
body { min-height: 100vh; }
```

I used above rule and got 937px height for the body element when inspecting it in chrome(full window). So with that in mind I used both height & min-height properties using percentage (ex 50%) as values and expected that child elements would inherit the height. But while inspecting the page, the child element ( I used <div> here) has 0px for Height. (I however got the expected result when I used values in pixels.)

Why don't child elements get the height from body element unlike in other instances like background-color or color or font-family where the child elements inherit them?

So what was going behind the scenes when I use percentage as values? Also if there are any useful resources for CSS, Please Provide them.

Edited:
[Body Has the min-height = 100vh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydkHC.png)

[child has the min-height = 100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWaEv.png)

[child has the min height = 937px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJMw3.png)

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducer, as a snippet.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS is a pretty reliable source for info on CSS. Please put your code into your question, not just a verbal explanation, so we can see what is happening.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent won't determine the child's height unless you give a 100% height to the child itself inside the parent.

That way you tell the child that it has to use up the full height of it's parent.

Setting the parent's height only provides space for the child to exists by it's default size. You need to tell it how much space it can use up.

If the dimensions would be inherited by all the children inside a parent (which is the body in your case) that would cause a huge mess, since a lot of elements would break out of their containers, because they would get in conflict while trying to fill up the space.

Comment: I did give 100%,75% & 50% to the child element (<div>) in different instances, and as said earlier I also declared min-height property to the parent element (<body>) & got 937px for height. Yet Browser shows "auto" value for <div> element's min-height (Even when i gave 100%). So my question again = I dont want auto for the child element inside <body> element. I am able to achieve this by using pixel as value and not by percent. Any Idea?

I am editing the above question to add images for your reference. Thanks for responding & i got your point on overflow as well, will make note of it.